# Traveling logistics for getting a TN-visa during COVID

Tags: canada, covid-19, tn-visa

I'm planning to switch jobs in the US as a Canadian, so I have to get a new TN visa for that. It's a time-sensitive offer, so I would need to travel to the YVR airport and get the visa there, before returning to the US to start my new job.

Normally pre-COVID, this basically involves buying a round-trip ticket to Vancouver, but I'm not quite sure how things work now with the pre-departure molecular test and all that.

In particular, is there a way to travel (by air) to Canada to stay for a day (or even half-a-day at the airport) without needing to go through the COVID tests/quarantines. And if I do need to get tested before traveling to Canada, is it possible to use the same test result to travel back to the US (without needing to do another test in Canada)?

Comment: Have you considered doing it at the land border? Or alternately, having your new company file I-129 so you don't have to leave the US?

Comment: @user102008 Hi. The land border (peace arch) is a bit far away from where I currently live (Southern California). And I'm not sure if the company is willing (or rather experienced enough) to file the I-129 for me.

Comment: In that case, the Mexican land border is pretty close. Alternately, you could fly to Seattle and drive to the Peace Arch.

Comment: @user102008 the Mexican border is obviously a good option in normal times, but will a Canadian citizen who doesn't actually hold any visa whatsoever be allowed [to cross into the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159550/19400)?  As I know you are aware, most Canadians in TN status don't actually have a visa; when they speak of getting "a new visa" at the border or at a preclearance facility, they actually mean getting "a new period of admission" or perhaps "a new I-94 form."  (Of course, I-94 forms are often no more than database records these days.)

Comment: @phoog: Are you talking about entry into Mexico or into the US? For entry into Mexico, there [doesn't seem to be any official restriction](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168650/3341). For entry into the US, they can enter by land or air since they are entering for work (which is essential travel). It doesn't matter whether they have a visa or not. As a Canadian citizen, they are eligible to seek entry into most types of nonimmigrant status without a visa, no matter at what border.

Comment: @user102008 into the US -- the question I linked to makes it pretty clear that entry into Mexico should pose little problem.  I had lost sight of the fact that exceptions to the US border closure were based on the purpose of travel rather than on the possession of a particular type of visa.  Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @user102008 Hello, thank you for such detailed response! On the official website, an example for "work-related travel" is given as "e.g. individuals working in the agriculture industry who must travel between the US and Mexico in furtherance of such work" (which seems to imply you are commuting between borders on a daily basis?), which does not seem to apply in my case. I'm slightly concerned that this will pose a problem for my return to the US perhaps?

Comment: @PeaBrane: It says "Individuals traveling to work in the United States". There is no requirement that you are commuting.

Comment: @user102008 Thank you. Just a quick follow-up unrelated question hope you don't mind. If I were to travel by air round-trip to Canada and back (within a 72-hour time window). Would I be able to just get the Covid test done in the US and use that for both the dpearting and returning flights (or do I need to do two tests for the two flights separately)

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer my question.

I decided to go through the CBP at the Vancouver International Airport in the end. The process was fairly smooth, and took less than 30 minutes, mostly consisting of me waiting.

Regarding covid-testing logistics, I got a PCR test at a CVS location in the US, and used the same negative test result for both the departing and returning flight. Note that the returning flight has to be within 3 days of the test as required by CDC.

For me, the most troublesome part wasn't even crossing the borders but rather trying to get the electronic BC vaccine card